# Is it decidable if a finite set of equations have only trivial models?

Tags: universal-algebra, decidability

Fix an algebraic signature $\Omega$. Let $F$ be a finite set of equations in $\Omega$. Is it decidable if the set $F$ has only trivial models? By trivial models, I mean one-element models. For example, if the set $F$ contains the equation $x=y$ then certainly it has only trivial models. However, perhaps the set $F$ does not contain $x=y$ but it still has only trivial models. I am wondering if the problem is decidable either way.

Comment: It immediately follows from the completeness theorem that the set of finite equational theories with only the trivial model is c.e. (just ask whether the theory in question entails $\forall x,y(x=y)$). I suspect that it is in fact c.e. complete (similarly to how the triviality problem for group presentations is c.e. complete) but I don't see how to prove this immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Perkins, Peter
Unsolvable problems for equational theories.
Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 8 (1967), 175-185.

states

**Theorem 14.** There is no effective method for determining whether or not
an arbitrary finite set of equations in one binary operation symbol and no
constants is consistent.

Comment: But how does this answer my specific question? What is the connection?

Comment: Every set of identities has a 1-element model, so a "consistent set of identities" is typically taken to mean a set of identities with a model of more than one element. What Perkins is saying is that it is undecidable whether a finite set of identities has a model of more than one element.

Comment: So, then, that means the converse problem of whether it has only 1-element models is also undecidable?

Comment: Yes. If you can effectively decide the answer to a problem, then you can effectively decide the answer to the complementary problem with the same algorithm by changing how you report the answer (interchange True $\leftrightarrow$ False).