# Is it decidable if a finite set of identities imply the commutative identity?

Tags: universal-algebra, binary-operations, decidability

This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: [Is it decidable if a finite set of equations have only trivial models?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387144/is-it-decidable-if-a-finite-set-of-equations-have-only-trivial-models). Let our signature be that of a single binary operation symbol $*$. Suppose I am given a finite set $S$ of identities in that signature, and I want to know whether the set $S$ implies the commutative identity $x*y=y*x$. Is that a decidable problem?

Comment: More generally, it would be interesting to know which (if any) equations $E$ are "decidably implied" by finite equational theories. I suspect that no such equations exist at all, but I don't immediately see the proof.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well, except for the trivial equation $t=t$, which is always implied by any set of equations..